# Sinon & React - check if mapToDispatch methods are called

Tags: reactjs, sinon

If you have mapDispatchToProps and you want to check that those methods ARE called in one of your component instance methods. So:

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    fetchPaymentDetails: () => dispatch(fetchPaymentDetails()),
    updatePaymentDetails: (payload) => dispatch(updatePaymentDetails(payload)),
    clearServerErrors: () => dispatch(clearServerErrors())
  }
}
```

Then in a method within the component:

```
 submit(e) {
    this.props.clearServerErrors();
 }
```

So we can trigger the `submit` function but then we want to know that `this.props.clearServerErrors` was indeed called.

So far I have tried many ways to test this involving sinon spys and stubs but I haven't been able to verify that the props method actually gets called.

It seems to me that the method spies that I pass in when mounting get overwritten by the `mapDispatchToProps`

Any suggestions on how to check that prop methods inside of `mapDispatchToProps` get called?

Answer (score 0):

You are really asking to test two different things:

1. That `mapToProps` will call your action helpers as you suspect
2. That your event handlers passed as props will be called when an event is triggered

I don't see the value in doing #1 for such simple functions, and anyway, in order to test `mapToProps` alone you would need to be able to inject the functions used in its definition to be able to test that they are called. Doing that would require seeing more of your code.

Alternatively, assuming the action creator functions are coming from another module you could use a [link seam](http://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/) to intercept calls to the action creators module and substitute the return values with your own.

Using `proxyquire` your test could look something like this:

```
const sinon = require('sinon');
let fakeActions;
let MyComponent, mapToProps;

function setupFakeActions() {
    fakeActions = { 
        fetchPaymentDetails: sinon.stub(), 
        /* etc ... */
    };

    const module = proxyquire('../src/my-component', {
        './actions': fakeActions
    });
    {MyComponent, mapToProps} = module;
}

describe('MyComponent propmapping', ()=> {
    setupFakeActions();
    it('should create a function that dispatches actions', () => {
        const dispatchStub = sinon.stub();
        const result = mapToProps(dispatchStub);
        result.fetchPaymentDetails();

        assert(dispatchStub.calledOnce);
        assert(fakeActions.fetchPaymentDetails.calledOnce);
        // more assertions: http://sinonjs.org/releases/v2.3.4/assertions/
        assert(dispatchStub.calledWith(fakeActions.fetchPaymentDetails));
    });
});
```

You have not tagged your question with redux, but assuming you use that, there is another way you could test that the functions do what they should, and that is of course to just create a store, trigger the action, and see if the right result comes out of the store, but that is quite obscure in intent and implementation, and so not recommended.

Now, the second point is more valuable, and quite straight forward using [Enzyme](https://github.com/airbnb/enzyme):

```
/* assuming existing test setup code for Mocha is in place: describe, it, ... */
it('calls assigned props on click events', () => {
    const props = {};
    props.fetchPaymentDetails = sinon.spy();
    const wrapper = shallow(
        <MyComponent fetchPaymentDetails={fetchPaymentDetails} />
    );
    wrapper.find('button').simulate('click');
    expect(props.fetchPaymentDetails).to.have.property('callCount', 1);
});
```